# Header in Google Table Charts has very choppy mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

In Google Visualization API when a table has a decent amount of data, the header is very choppy when scrolling with the mouse wheel up and down.

I have here a test that shows what I mean (ignore the fact that the header doesn't have any text, no idea why it doesn't detect it and it's a separate issue).

Is there a way to make scrolling in this situation more decent?

Check out the GIF: 
[image]

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBasic,
  packages: ['table']
});

function drawBasic() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w1vaFAPTE440jc2cpYGftXSaPwGxU_x7iQRSGK35oYc/edit#gid=0&headers=1'
  );
  query.setQuery('SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }


  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var options = {
    title: 'test',
    height: '80vh',
    showRowNumber: true,
    page: "enable",
  pageSize: 500,
  allowHtml: true
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options)
  
}
```

```css
#chart_div{
  margin-top: 20px;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.google-visualization-table-tr-head {
  
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: which browser are you using? seems ok in chrome...

Comment: @WhiteHat Chrome latest build but I checked in Edge and IE as well.  You don't see the header (red) lagging behind when scrolling up to the top with your mouse wheel? Update: It looks like in Chrome, it only occurs on 4k monitors. In Edge and IE, it happens on 1080p as well. (Checked on several performance laptops)

Comment: @WhiteHat please check the GIF.